# function wrapped in parens

Tags: javascript, parentheses

Why does this return a syntax error:

```
function(foo){console.log(foo)}
```

I'd expect this to return the value of the function, hence return itself, and not assign it to anything, but i get a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

but this works:

```
(function(foo){console.log(foo)})
```

Please explain what purpose those wrapping parenthesis serve. I've been told that parens are used to "increase readability" but in this case there definitely is more purpose served.

Can you please go into further detail about use about () ? Say you were to translate that line of code to prose, what would the () read like? I am trying as well to describe this concept to other people, and need to transmit its meaning so that everybody can understand it. The question i'm trying to answer, is what do the ()'s mean? Do they have a semantic value, and what is it?

Comment: in the first example an identifier is missing. In the second example when you wrap with parens you're creating an expression function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first example is a function *declaration*. It doesn't have an identifier, which is a syntax error. Here's the [grammar for a function declaration](http://es5.github.com/#x13) (notice that *Identifier* is not optional):

> *FunctionDeclaration* :
>
> `function` *Identifier* `(` *FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub>* ) `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

By wrapping it in parentheses you turn it into a function *expression* (an anonymous one). You could execute it by adding a pair of invoking parentheses after:

```
(function(foo){console.log(foo)})("hello"); //Will log 'hello'
```

Here's the gammar for a function expression (now the identifier is optional):

> *FunctionExpression* :
>
> `function` *Identifier<sub>opt</sub>* `(` *FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub>* ) `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

---

**How the parentheses turn a function declaration into a function expression**

In this case, the parentheses are parsed as a "[grouping operator](http://es5.github.com/#x11.1.6)". The grammar for the grouping operator is as follows:

> *PrimaryExpression* :
>
> `(` *Expression* `)`

The grouping operator can only contain an expression, so your function is parsed as an expression rather than a declaration (obviously, in your exact example, the function can't be a declaration since it doesn't have an identifier).

Comment: Thank you James! But i'm still missing the part about the ()'s. They seem to hold misterious powers, being able to change priority of operations (1+1)*2 and being able to change a declaration to an expression. How do i distinguish between the two cases? Is there a give away charachteristic, or how does this work?

Comment: @user436118 - You're welcome :) Check my edit, I've added in a bit about how the parentheses turn a declaration into an expression.

Comment: So, in essence, () turns ANYTHING within it to an expression, and groups it together. Is that the gist?

Comment: @user436118 - Yes, as long as that thing can be parsed as an expression according to the grammar. For example, `(var a)` will fail because `var` is a statement, not an expression. Functions can be parsed as expressions, so they are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

This is because without the `()`, the `function(){}` line is a [function declaration](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#function-declaration), while **with** the `()` is an [expression](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#function-expression).

function declarations are a strange beasts, they made available everywhere in the scope they are defined in *before* code execution, so snippets like this works:

```
foo();
function foo() { console.log('foo'); }
```

Comment: check the part of the standard titled "question about surrounding parentheses"
http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/chapter-5-functions/#question-about-surrounding-parentheses]